# TCP buffer size analysis

Tags: windows, windows-xp, tcp

Is it possible to query the current size (or some kind of graph of the buffer-size over time for that matter) of the TCP buffer of a connection?

> Each endpoint of a TCP connection will have a buffer for storing data that is transmitted 
>   over the network before the application is ready to read the data. [source](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Topics/83.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The window size in the TCP header reflects the size of the remaining buffer on each end. You can graph this using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to both capture and analyze traffic (This isn't real time, but is usually how this sort of thing is done). Choose Custom IO Graph under Statistics and do something like the following (You need to choose Advanced for the Y-Axis):

[image]

The above graphs the window size for all packets where the source address in the packet is 10.7.0.127.

Comment: If you think it is filling up you can also use `tcp.analysis.zero_window`